# How to pass "extra" keyword arguments to a lambda?

Tags: ruby

There is this code:

```rb
a = -> (var:) { "Var: #{var}" }
```

It works successfully when used like this:

```rb
a.call(var: "Hi!")
```

But how can I pass arguments to `.call` that might not be used?

```rb
a.call(var: "Hi!", extra: "")
```

> ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :extra)

For example, I want to decide in different places whether I need to use certain variables in texts.

---

I have a root location where all named arguments are always passed to `.call`. And I need to pass `lambda` in other places, where only the necessary arguments are described.

Comment: You could make `var` a hash and only change the code in the block.

Comment: It's not because of lambda, kwargs work such way. You can use some default kwarg `extra: nil` or use hash instead of kwargs

Answer (score 2):

You can choose only the args you're interested in inside the proc, and ignore the others by using "splatted" keyword arguments:

```rb
a = ->(**kwargs){ "Var #{kwargs[:var]}" }

a.call(var: "foo") #=> "Var foo"

a.call(var: "foo", extra: "bar") #=> "Var foo"
```

Is that what you're looking for?